# How do I post form by clicking a checkbox without refreshing the page?

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms

I'm making a home automation system with raspberry pi and raspbian. I'm gonna design a web page that contains some checkboxes to control the lights via relays. I need a web code that contains a checkbox. When I click that checkbox, php will execute a python code file which controls the relays. I heard posting forms without refreshing the page can be done by ajax and javascript. But I'm not familiar with those languages. Could you guys, please show me a simple checkbox example which is when I check it, it will make php exec() some file and uncheck it, it will make php exec() another file.

Here is the example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <title>Raspberry Pi</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="checkbox" class="iclass" />
        <script>
    $("input.iclass").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post("post.php", {param1: value, param2: value});
});
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And the post.php just gives and `alert('Succesful!');` for now. But somehow it's not working.

Comment: If you need to call Python ultimately, consider using a web server written in Python, such as django, to limit the amount of language barriers you have to cross. However if you need to use a PHP server the answer by Praveen Kumar provides a simple example how to do just that.

Comment: At some point, I will need php and jQuery for the future stages of my project. However I took a look to django framework and It seemed to me very powerful. I'm gonna use it some day. Thanks for the advice @Cu3PO42

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) library. You can use something like this:

```
$("input.checkbox-class").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post("/path/to/php/script.php", {param1: value, param2: value});
});
```

And the source of `/path/to/php/script.php` will have:

```
<?php
    exec("system");
?>
```

A sample code with full HTML would be:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <title>Raspberry Pi</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="checkbox" />
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $.post("/path/to/php/script.php", {param1: value, param2: value});
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You will need jQuery for that

Comment: @GerardvanHelden Info added. `:)`

Comment: I used the sample html code above. But didn't worked for me. When I checked or unchecked the checkbox nothing happened.
I navigated my php script directly from the browser, the relays worked. But didn't able to call trigger php file by clicking the checkbox. Thanks.

Comment: Here is the htm code:

`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="checkbox" />
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $.post("/trigger.php", {param1: value, param2: value});
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>`

and my trigger.php file:

`<php
exec("sudo python /home/pi/openrelay.py");
?>`

When I navigate the trigger.php directly, system works. Otherwise not. Thank you
@PraveenKumar

Comment: @OnurAlkan This needs jQuery to be accessible. Can you do one thing? Copy `jquery-1.9.1.min.js` to your local and reference it and see?

Comment: @PraveenKumar I tried to call jQuery from local as well but didn't worked for me again. Raspberry Pi itself, has internet connection, page should include the jQuery. I'm tring to figure out the problem. I'm gonna inform here if I can fix it. Thank you.

Comment: @OnurAlkan Can you use the same script on your browser and try it out?